# SQL query : need help in getting this query right

Tags: sql, function, parameters, ssms, isnull

I have this code

```
ISNULL(@param, ") = "
```

Can someone explain how this `= ”`  is working?

Answer (score 0):

If the value of @param is not defined (null), or it is an empty string, it returns true.
isnull is a function that checks if your first param is not defined (null) and if so it replaces it with the second parameter (in this case, empty string).